# Docker Volume Issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, devops, docker-volume

I have been trying to use docker volume to persist my app. I'm new to docker and I am doing this on a mac. Every time I run my docker command I get an error saying my workdir is "invalid mode". Any help would be appreciated

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

EXPOSE 5200
```

Running my image with this

```
docker run -p 5200:5200 -it --name server -v $(pwd):/usr/app -v /usr/app/node_modules server-docker
```

This is the error i receive

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/app.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: i added the answer .  feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with your Docker volume mount syntax in this part: -v /usr/app/node_modules. Docker is expecting the volume mount syntax to be in the form :, but in your command, it appears that the container directory path is missing.

You're already mounting the current directory ($(pwd)) into /usr/app in the container. You should never mount node_modules into the container because node_modules directory get created when you docker run the npm run install command from the dockerfile.
Best solution would be to create `.dockerignore` file on the location where dockerfile is and add node_modules to the ignore list like this to the `.dockerignore` file.

```
node_modules
```

After that you can run following command to start the container.

```
docker run -p 5200:5200 -it --name server -v $(pwd):/usr/app server-docker
```

I would suggest to learn multistage build and about `dockerignore`. Just google it for node or whatever framework you are using.

Comment: thank you very much, i did as you said and it worked out pretty much. I have a question the course im following said that when you add the "-v /usr/app/node_modules" its to make sure that your container retains the node_modules after the installing when your mapping your ports to run the container.

Comment: Your welcome

Whatever course is saying, is not best practice and you should never persist node_modules in production and development.

If your internet connection is slow or metered, would suggest you to rent a vps and ssh into it through VS Code and program on it but persisting node_modules is always going to create problems, so dont do that.

Comment: Thank you so much, i would stop that practice